# VSCode can not find .NET sdk

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu

I'm using VSCode on Ubuntu and I installed .NET sdk through `sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic`. Then after opening a project I get the "No .NET SDKs were found". I tried writing on the settings.json file but to no avail. Neither the ".bashrc" file works. Any idea on this one?

Output of `which dotnet` command : /usr/bin/dotnet

 What am I getting from inside VSCode Integrated Terminal:
[image]

Comment: Can you do a "which dotnet" on the terminal?

Comment: Can you also post the exact command you used to install? Are you sure, you installed the sdk, not just the runtime?

Comment: @Fildor I updated the answer accordingly. I tried uninstalling the snap version and installed it through ```apt``` yet it again cant find an sdk

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was the removal of .NET installation through `snap` package manager and executing this command:

- sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list

Then install .NET through apt.